# replace with files from multiple directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a large amount of JPEG-files that have been sorted and placed in several different directories. Unfortunately these directories were lost - although I was able to restore them from an older version. However all the files are corrupted.

Luckily I still have the JPEG-files that aren't sorted and I want to replace the corrupted files with these healthy files by filename. So basically go through the unsorted files and match them with the sorted files.
I found out that by using the command `replace` I'm able to do this and it works perfectly with one exception: I can only go through 1 source directory at a time. This is a problem because the unsorted JPEG-files are located in ~2000 different directories.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
replace "folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\*.jpg" "sorted_images_dir" /s
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
replace "folder1\*EVERY SUBDIRECTORY OF folder1*\*.jpg" "sorted_images_dir" /s
```

Is this possible on the commandline or would I have to create a batch file? If so, any advice for this? It seems like it would be a rather simple task.

Comment: is a powershell answer good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read `HELP FOR` and try `FOR /D %a in (*) do @echo %a` this way you might iterate over all the folders in the current directory.

You might then try `FOR /D /R %a in (*) do @echo %a` to iterate recursively on all the folders and subfolders.

So, finally you can try

```
FOR /D /R %a in (*) do @replace "%a\*.jpg" "sorted_images_dir" /s
```